# Amazon SP-API with Notifications API (SQS Queue) triggering same reports 10 times

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

Please find most of the information in the title.

We receive notifications for the same autogenerated reports always 10 times at once from the Selling Partner API. You can also see this in the following screenshot as except from the SQS console.

We setup a subscription for the REPORT_PROCESSING_FINISHED notification event using the notifications API just following the setup guide.

Is this a bug or how can we find out why the notification comes 10 times at once? We only subscribed once for the reports (as it is technically also only possible to subscribe once) and therefore would expect any report finishing notification to only be published once. As the screenshot shows the reportId is always the same (the time difference comes from processing each message after another).

[image][image]